# mysqli Select does not properly work

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I have a php file ie. index.php and from this I call with Java another PHPfile in which I select data from a database, I call the file like this:

```
$.get("ociPHP/DBtoOCI.php", { uniqueReferenceKey: Reference  } )
```

in DBtoOCI.php i use this query:

```
 $sqlReturnExistingOCI = "SELECT * FROM ociorder WHERE reference = '".$uniquekey."'";

        $result = $conn->query($sqlReturnExistingOCI);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
               echo   echo '<input type="hidden" class="descriptionfield"  name="NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION['.$count.']" value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION'], ENT_QUOTES) .'">';

 $sqlDeleteRow = "DELETE FROM ociorder WHERE `reference`= '" .$uniquekey. "'";
                             $conn->query($sqlDeleteRow); 
                             if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlDeleteRow)) {
                                  echo "Record deleted successfully" . $uniquekey;
                              } else {
                                  echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
                              }
}
```

then in index.php I append this echo to a div. If I call this DBtoOCI.php for the first time, then I nicely see the data appended. But if I call it for the second time(while the row is deleted already and if there is already a new row with uniqueKey but other description data) then I again get the old data back which is already out of the database. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when calling a .php file with JS, where you have select statement, then at every call I need to call data with a different uniquekey. This works

Answer (score 2):

Because you execute delete query two times

```
$conn->query($sqlDeleteRow); // first time
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlDeleteRow)) {// second time
echo "Record deleted successfully" . $uniquekey;
} else {
echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Just execute only one time

```
if ($conn->query($sqlDeleteRow)) {
echo "Record deleted successfully" . $uniquekey;
} else {
echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Don't assign direct value to query

Read [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: I now execute the query 1 time but still getting old data, I will try to use prepare statement now, do I maybe also need to free the result after using the statement and echoing the results?

Comment: can SELECT * also be used with a prepared statement?

Comment: Not able you understand your requirement. yes you can free your result after execution your query.

Comment: Yes you can use it as `SELECT * FROM ociorder WHERE reference = ?`

Comment: Ok I will try to get the results with prepare statement, I respond when I got it working

Comment: I now got this:
http://pastebin.com/SCc3Bmux

It adds the echo to my html and it then afterwards delete the row with the uniquekey(reference). But then if I add new data with same reference number then it still gets the old data and not the new one while echoing